# android multi-line keyboard and done

Tags: android, keyboard

I have a multi-line textbox and the keyboard shows "carriage return". How do I show both a carriage return and a done button or how do you action a "done" if the user is finished?

Answer (score 1):

You can only chose one ImeOptions so either carriage return or done/go can be used. If you want both make a simple button next to the EditTextView that does the action done/go and don't set an ImeOption on the EditTextView.